# Documentation for ffmpeg progress output

Tags: ffmpeg

With `-progress` continuous  data about the transcoding can be posted or written to a file. Where can I find documentation what which key means exactly? Specifically, `q` (Quality) and `speed` but also the other ones

```
frame=161
fps=39.6
stream_0_0_q=16.0
stream_1_0_q=13.0
stream_2_0_q=13.0
stream_3_0_q=11.0
stream_4_0_q=10.0
bitrate=N/A
total_size=N/A
out_time_ms=5456211
out_time=00:00:05.456211
dup_frames=10
drop_frames=0
speed=1.34x
progress=continue
```

You get similar output with the verbose logging. I haven't found it in the source code either where I thought I could find more information about it

Comment: Believe speed is the writing rate compared to the playback rate.  q, not sure.